# TWS job failing. ERROR jobmon was unable to retrieve user information

Tags: tivoli-work-scheduler

I am configuring TWS job in one of our application windows server but when the job triggered it is throwing the below exception. I am using domain user to execute the job.

> AWSBDW079E Jobman could not run the job because the system call used to launch the job failed: Jobmon was unable to retrieve user information.

Do I need any special permissions for the user to run the job.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, TWS needs userid and password in order to impersonate the user.

You have to specify the USER object with the appropriate Workstation name, userid and password.

Using Dynamic Agents there are also other options using Executable job types, e.g. you can store the password locally on the agent with the parm utility.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the issue. The issue was with the user permissions. The user which is used to run the job on the workstation must have the below permissions.

1. Allow log on locally
2. Log on as a batch job